# Clickable dropdown Menu in Navigation Bar not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu inside the navigation bar which should show up on user click and disappear on clicking anywhere outside(like Facebook's dropdown menu having logout,etc.). But the dropdown isn't working the way it should. I have searched everywhere on StackOverflow and the internet but unable to find a solution. I want to implement it using CSS and JavaScript only, since I don't understand jQuery and other languages.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ahy32yn/9/

The codes I have implemented are as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="movies.php">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="faq.php">FAQs</a>
   </li>
   <li class="user" style="float:right;">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn" onclick="UserDropdown()">Dropdown</a>
      <ul id="UserContent" class="user-content">
          <li>
            <a href="profile.php">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="gifts.php">My Gifts</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;     
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;  
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
}

li
{
  float: left;
}

li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

li a:hover
{
  background-color: #333333;
}

.user
{
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.dropbtn
{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.user-content 
{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.user-content a 
{
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.user-content a:hover 
{
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.show 
{
  display:block;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function UserDropdown() {
    document.getElementById("UserContent").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) 
{
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) 
  {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("user-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) 
     {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show'))
      {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. The Fiddle doesn't even show the dropdown on clicking whereas it shows up on my localhost like this:

[image: Localhost dropdown output]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/8ahy32yn/13/) ? The behavior you want is currently working, I just apply some CSS to style it better I think.

```
.show 
{
  display:block;
  width: 245px; 
  right: 0; 
  left: auto;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

With `height: auto` on the `ul` and removing `overflow: hidden` on the `ul` parent you can do it the way you want : [See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ahy32yn/16)

Comment: Thanks. But the dropdown is displaying elements inside the navigation bar itself. It should display elements vertically. Can you help?

Comment: No problem, with `height: auto` on the `ul` and removing `overflow: hidden` on the `ul` parent you can do it : https://jsfiddle.net/8ahy32yn/16/

Comment: Thank you so much Vincent! Also, I was wondering whether it'd be possible to show the dropdown list below the link "Dropdown"? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: You're welcome ! Since it's in absolute position, you can play with `top` value to achieve that, like this : https://jsfiddle.net/8ahy32yn/18/

Comment: Yes I figured that out same time haha! Thanks a lot anyways. Cheers :D

Comment: Glad it helps, don't forget to validate the subject if it's ok for you :)

Answer (score 0):

A closing brace is missing in the javascript section, the reason not working in fiddle

This link might help

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp